# XBee and watchdog timer transmission not working

Tags: arduino, watchdog, xbee, zigbee

I've created a [sketch](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch) that uses a watchdog timer that runs every eight seconds. I've used a counter to wait 64 seconds (about a minute).

In addition, I've used the pin hibernation mode on the XBee. The XBee communication together with the pin hibernation work properly. If I add the [watchdog timer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer) it stops working. Is the program restarted from the last row executed before the watchdog interrupt?

```
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <avr/power.h>
#include <avr/wdt.h>
#include <XBee.h>

XBeeAddress64 coordAddr = XBeeAddress64(0x0013a200, 0x4090c5a6);
uint8_t xbeePayload[] = "Hello";
XBee xbee = XBee();

ZBTxRequest zbTx = ZBTxRequest();
ZBTxStatusResponse txStatus = ZBTxStatusResponse();

int XBee_pin = 9;          // This pin wakes up the XBee and puts it to sleep.
int counter = 0;

void sendData() {
    zbTx.setAddress64(coordAddr);
    zbTx.setAddress16(0xFFFE);
    zbTx.setPayload(xbeePayload);
    zbTx.setPayloadLength(sizeof(xbeePayload));
    xbee.send(zbTx);
}

ISR(WDT_vect)
{
    counter++;
}

void enterSleep(void)
{
    set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
    sleep_enable();

    /* Now enter sleep mode. */
    sleep_mode();

    /* The program will continue from here after the WDT timeout */
    sleep_disable(); /* First thing to do is disable sleep. */

    /* Re-enable the peripherals. */
    power_all_enable();
}

void setup()
{
    // To reduce power, setup all pins as inputs with without any pullups
    /*for(int x = 1 ; x < 18 ; x++){
          pinMode(x, INPUT);
          digitalWrite(x, LOW);
    }*/

    pinMode(XBee_pin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(XBee_pin, HIGH);
    xbee.begin(9600);
    delay(5000);

    /*** Setup the WDT ***/

    /* Clear the reset flag. */
    MCUSR &= ~(1 << WDRF);

    /* In order to change WDE or the prescaler, we need to
     * set WDCE (this will allow updates for 4 clock cycles).
     */
    WDTCSR |= (1 << WDCE) | (1 << WDE);

    /* Set new watchdog timeout prescaler value */
    WDTCSR = 1 << WDP0 | 1 << WDP3; /* 8.0 seconds */

    /* Enable the WD interrupt (note no reset). */
    WDTCSR |= _BV(WDIE);

    //Serial.println("Initialisation complete.");
    //delay(100); //Allow for serial print to complete.

    ADCSRA &= ~(1 << ADEN); //Disable ADC
    ACSR = (1 << ACD);  //Disable Analog Comparator
    DIDR0 = 0x3E;    //Disable digital input buffers on ADC1-ADC5 pins
    DIDR1 = (1 << AIN1D)|(1 << AIN0D); //Disable digital input buffer on AIN1/0

    power_twi_disable();
    power_spi_disable();
    power_usart0_disable();
    //power_timer0_disable(); //Needed for delay_ms
    power_timer1_disable();
    power_timer2_disable();
}

void loop()
{
    if(counter == 8)
    {
        counter = 0;
        pinMode(XBee_pin, OUTPUT);
        digitalWrite(XBee_pin, LOW);
        delay(5000);
        sendData();
        delay(2000);
        pinMode(XBee_pin, INPUT);
        digitalWrite(XBee_pin, HIGH);

        /* Re-enter sleep mode. */
        enterSleep();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

enterSleep() needs to be outside the if statement. Your current implementation spins in the loop(), waits for 8 watchdog timeouts, executes the code once, sleeps, wakes up and does the same spin. The code should look like this I believe.

```
void loop()
{
  if(counter == 8)
  {
     counter = 0;
    pinMode(XBee_pin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(XBee_pin, LOW);
    delay(5000);    
    sendData();
    delay(2000);
    pinMode(XBee_pin, INPUT);    
    digitalWrite(XBee_pin, HIGH);
  }
  /* Re-enter sleep mode. */
  enterSleep();
}
```

Also, be aware that the watchdog is still running while your delays occur. It may trigger again during your if statement, you should issue a wdt_reset() in a few places like:

```
void loop()
{
  if(counter == 8)
  {
     counter = 0;
    pinMode(XBee_pin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(XBee_pin, LOW);
    delay(5000); 
    wdt_reset();
    sendData();
    wdt_reset();
    delay(2000);
    pinMode(XBee_pin, INPUT);    
    digitalWrite(XBee_pin, HIGH);
  }
  /* Re-enter sleep mode. */
  enterSleep();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's going to take less than 8 seconds ... I think it should be better to disable temporarily the watchdog timer ... what do you suggest me ?

Comment: The transmission is now working. This is the sketch: http://pastebin.com/tFt2vJRm
It's using some power saving options, the power hibernation of the xBee pin and the power_done mode.
The problem is that I need to wait for a really long time (about 10 seconds) before I can send a packet. 
Where am i wrong?

Comment: Which xBee module are you using? I want to see if I can craft something up that would use an interrupt + watchdog (safety timer) so you can sleep the micro while waiting for the xBee to come up.

Comment: xBee PRO Series 2 with RPSMA connector

Comment: You might want to figure out why it is taking so long to get up. I read in a different xBee spec that the wake up time should be on the order of milliseconds not seconds. You should debug that huge delay first since it will reduce the amount of time the xBee device is on. If the xBee is awake that whole time and you sleep the Arduino, you aren't saving that much power in the end.